# Joining two tables back on them selves together

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, left-join

I am trying to write a query with some fancy joins.  I know this can be done, but I am not remembering how to do it.

Here is my query as it is now:

```
SELECT  parentLink.SourceWorkItemID, parentLink.TargetWorkItemID,
            childLink.SourceWorkItemID, childLink.TargetWorkItemID, 
            childLink.WorkItemLinkTypeSK--,childLinkType.LinkName
FROM    dbo.FactWorkItemLinkHistory parentLink
        JOIN dbo.DimWorkItemLinkType parentLinkType (NOLOCK)
            ON parentLink.WorkItemLinkTypeSK = parentLinkType.WorkItemLinkTypeSK
        LEFT JOIN dbo.FactWorkItemLinkHistory childLink (NOLOCK)
            ON parentLink.TargetWorkItemID = childLink.SourceWorkItemID
            AND childLink.RemovedByPersonSK IS NULL
            AND childLink.WorkItemLinkTypeSK IN 
               (SELECT  sublink.WorkItemLinkTypeSK
                FROM    dbo.DimWorkItemLinkType sublink
                WHERE   sublink.LinkName = 'Child'
               )
        --LEFT JOIN dbo.DimWorkItemLinkType childLinkType (NOLOCK)
        --  ON childLink.WorkItemLinkTypeSK = childLinkType.WorkItemLinkTypeSK  
        --  AND childLinkType.LinkName = 'Child'            
WHERE   parentLink.SourceWorkItemID = 1917
        AND parentLink.RemovedByPersonSK IS NULL        
        AND parentLinkType.LinkName = 'Releases Story'
```

I have tried to get this to run without the `select` clause in the `from` part of my query, but it keeps eluding me.

The result I am looking for is something this:

```
1917    1915    1915    1916    2
1917    1913    1913    1914    2
1917    1913    1913    4349    2
1917    1921    1921    1922    2
1917    1918    NULL    NULL    NULL
1917    1920    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I get that result using the `select` in the `from` clause, but I would rather not use a `select` there if I can avoid it.

I tried making these changes:

1. Uncomment the last join (and `childLinkType.LinkName` in the main select clause)
2. Remove the unwanted `select` clause (the line above the last join).

When I do I get this:

```
1917    1915    1915    1916    2   Child
1917    1915    1915    1917    20  NULL
1917    1915    1915    1919    7   NULL
1917    1915    1915    1911    4   NULL
1917    1913    1913    1914    2   Child
1917    1913    1913    1917    20  NULL
1917    1913    1913    1911    4   NULL
1917    1913    1913    4349    2   Child
1917    1921    1921    1922    2   Child
1917    1921    1921    1917    20  NULL
1917    1918    1918    1919    7   NULL
1917    1918    1918    1912    4   NULL
1917    1918    1918    1917    20  NULL
1917    1920    1920    1911    4   NULL
1917    1920    1920    1917    20  NULL
```

That is too many rows.  And the I don't want nulls matching on the DimWorkItemLinkType table.  So I make the last join an inner join.  Then I get this:

```
1917    1915    1915    1916    2   Child
1917    1913    1913    1914    2   Child
1917    1913    1913    4349    2   Child
1917    1921    1921    1922    2   Child
```

That has removed the items that don't have a "child" (1918 and 1920 from the first data set).  I still need them in my results.

Any ideas how I can remove the select (in the from clause) and still get this to give me the first set of results?

NOTE: I am running this against the TFS_Warehouse database on TFS 2010 server (using the tables that are approved for reporting purposes).

Comment: Seems like you might get more answers if you posed the question generically (like your title suggests), rather than giving us a huge question with the specifics. Seems like no one else wants to tackle this either. Just a thought.  :-P

Comment: If you just want to get rid of the subquery then I suggest you can use a temp table and run joins on it instead.

Comment: I don't have a TFS_Warehouse running. You have posted the outputs but ommitted the inputs. If you post actual inputs for given outputs, more people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I won't pretend I really understand your question -- as others have said, it might be worth trying to break it down and simplify it -- and I don't have a TFS_Warehouse, but I'm going to take a chance and guess that you're looking for a structure something like this (untested, obviously):

```
SELECT  parentLink.SourceWorkItemID, parentLink.TargetWorkItemID,
            childLink.SourceWorkItemID, childLink.TargetWorkItemID, 
            childLink.WorkItemLinkTypeSK--,childLinkType.LinkName
FROM    dbo.FactWorkItemLinkHistory parentLink
        JOIN dbo.DimWorkItemLinkType parentLinkType (NOLOCK)
            ON parentLink.WorkItemLinkTypeSK = parentLinkType.WorkItemLinkTypeSK
        LEFT JOIN 
          (dbo.FactWorkItemLinkHistory childLink (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN dbo.DimWorkItemLinkType childLinkType (NOLOCK)
              ON childLink.WorkItemLinkTypeSK = childLinkType.WorkItemLinkTypeSK  
              AND childLinkType.LinkName = 'Child')
          ON parentLink.TargetWorkItemID = childLink.SourceWorkItemID
          AND childLink.RemovedByPersonSK IS NULL
WHERE   parentLink.SourceWorkItemID = 1917
        AND parentLink.RemovedByPersonSK IS NULL        
        AND parentLinkType.LinkName = 'Releases Story'
```

Comment: Perfect!  Worked just perfect!  Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!